# Change UIView constraints in chained animations

Tags: ios, swift, animation, constraints, chained

I'm trying to create a **chained animation** of a UIButton with a delay between the two animations:

```
    let firstAnimation: TimeInterval = 0.3
    let secondAnimation: TimeInterval = 0.35
    let delay: TimeInterval = 2.0
    let animationDuration: TimeInterval = firstAnimation + secondAnimation + delay

    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: firstAnimation / animationDuration, animations: {
            self.enterEqualWidthConstraint.isActive = false
            self.enterWidthConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.width
            self.enterWidthConstraint.isActive = true
            self.enterButton.setTitle("HAVE FUN!", for: .normal)
            print("now1")
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })

        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: delay / animationDuration, relativeDuration: secondAnimation / animationDuration, animations: {
            print("now2")
            self.enterWidthConstraint.constant = 0
            self.enterButton.setTitle("ENTER", for: .normal)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

The output gets printed at the same time:

> now1
>   now2

And **even** *self.enterWidthConstraint.constat* **changes before the delay**.

How can I have a delay between the two chained animations?
**If the constraint changes before the delay the text that's inside the UIButton disappears.**
I need to do some other animations after these ones but I'm stuck at the first ones.

**UPDATE**

I tried the approach without keyframes but the **delay** doesn't work:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.30, animations: {
        self.enterEqualWidthConstraint.isActive = false
        self.enterWidthConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.width
        self.enterWidthConstraint.isActive = true
        self.enterButton.setTitle("HAVE FUN!", for: .normal)
        print("now1")
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, delay: 2.0, options: [], animations: {
            print("now2")
            self.enterButton.setTitle("ENTER", for: .normal)
            self.enterWidthConstraint.constant = 0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    })
```

It does the same thing.

Comment: First of all, you should add the print now1 & now2 statements in the completion block instead of the animations {} .. that will print the proper time at which both the animations complete. What are you animating ? Do you see any autolayout issues in the console while animation ?

Comment: No autolayout issues. The prints are there to know when the animation starts. I don't care when they end I care when they start because the second one has to start with delay

Comment: try setting             self.enterButton.setTitle("ENTER", for: .normal)
 before second animation starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.30, animations: {
        self.enterEqualWidthConstraint.isActive = false
        self.enterWidthConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.width
        self.enterWidthConstraint.isActive = true
        self.enterButton.setTitle("HAVE FUN!", for: .normal)
        print("now1")
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { _ in

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

              self.enterButton.setTitle("ENTER", for: .normal)

              UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: {

                     print("now2")
                     self.enterWidthConstraint.constant = 0
                     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
             }, completion: nil)
        })
});
```

another way is to start two independent animations instead of chaining it

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.30, animations: {
            self.enterEqualWidthConstraint.isActive = false
            self.enterWidthConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.width
            self.enterWidthConstraint.isActive = true
            self.enterButton.setTitle("HAVE FUN!", for: .normal)
            print("now1")
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { _ in             
                  self.enterButton.setTitle("ENTER", for: .normal)
   });

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, delay: 2.0, options: [], animations: {
        print("now2")
        self.enterWidthConstraint.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I already used this approach and it's the only one that works. Is this a correct way to do it?

Comment: of course, it's no way wrong. I hope you understand why your other approaches are failing here

Comment: the reason is you need to show the text Enter for 2 seconds before it animates again