# How to animate constraints one by one in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nslayoutconstraint, uiviewanimationtransition

I have 6 views. I want to animate the constraints one by one, ie, i need the animation on second view only after first, then after second the third and so on. I have added the code in the completion handler of the animations, but it is not working. initial value of all the constraint is set to 300 in storyboard. I want to change it to 0 one by one. Now, only the first animation is working. This is what i have done.

```
layoutTopFirst.constant = 0.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self->layoutTopSecond.constant = 0.0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            self->layoutTopThird.constant = 0.0;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                self->layoutTopFourth.constant = 0.0;
                [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    self->layoutTopFifth.constant = 0.0;
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        self->layoutTopSixth.constant = 0.0;
                        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            
                        }];
                    }];
                }];
            }];
        }];
    }];
```

How to do animations one after another?

Comment: "It is not working" in what way? Do all animate at once? Do none animate? Does only the first animate? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Stonz2 I have updated the question. Only the first one is animating now

Comment: could you add a log in each completion to see what is happening ? Note, that is not exactly a Swift topic, but no matter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change UIView constraints in chained animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362866/change-uiview-constraints-in-chained-animations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If only the first one is animating, make sure that

- your other five constraint references all point to different vertical constraints ... if they were `nil` for example, you won't see any changes;
- that they're all `isActive`;
- that there aren't any other constraints that are preventing the updated constants from yielding changes.

---

For what it's worth, you might consider eliminating your tower of completion handlers with keyframe animation, e.g.

```
CGFloat relativeDuration = 1.0 / 6.0;

[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:6 delay:0 options:kNilOptions animations:^{
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:relativeDuration animations:^{
        self.topConstraint1.constant = 0;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:1.0 * relativeDuration relativeDuration:relativeDuration animations:^{
        self.topConstraint2.constant = 0;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:2.0 * relativeDuration relativeDuration:relativeDuration animations:^{
        self.topConstraint3.constant = 0;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:3.0 * relativeDuration relativeDuration:relativeDuration animations:^{
        self.topConstraint4.constant = 0;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:4.0 * relativeDuration relativeDuration:relativeDuration animations:^{
        self.topConstraint5.constant = 0;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:5.0 * relativeDuration relativeDuration:relativeDuration animations:^{
        self.topConstraint6.constant = 0;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
} completion:nil];
```

Or, even simpler:

```
NSArray <NSLayoutConstraint *> *constraints = @[self.topConstraint1, self.topConstraint2, self.topConstraint3, self.topConstraint4, self.topConstraint5, self.topConstraint6];

CGFloat relativeDuration = 1.0 / (CGFloat) constraints.count;

[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:totalDuration delay:0 options:kNilOptions animations:^{
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < constraints.count; i++) {
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime: ((CGFloat) i) * relativeDuration relativeDuration:relativeDuration animations:^{
            constraints[i].constant = 0;
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    }
} completion:nil];
```

That yields:

[image]

Comment: I used keyframe animation & it worked. Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you showed all your code (how you setup the constraints, etc).

But, here is a quick example.

It creates 6 labels, with top constraints at 100. Tap the "Do Anim" button to animated them to Top: 0.0 ... tap again to animate back to 100:

```
#import "SequentialAnimViewController.h"

@interface SequentialAnimViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *views;
    NSMutableArray *topConstraints;
}
@end

@implementation SequentialAnimViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(animViews) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Do Anim" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:1.0];
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    
    [button.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:[self.view centerXAnchor]].active = YES;
    [button.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:[self.view centerYAnchor]].active = YES;
    [button.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:200.0].active = YES;

    views = [NSMutableArray new];
    topConstraints = [NSMutableArray new];
    
    CGFloat x = 40.0;
    CGFloat w = 40.0;

    UILayoutGuide *g = [self.view safeAreaLayoutGuide];

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        UILabel *v = [UILabel new];
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        v.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        v.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        v.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [self.view addSubview:v];
        [v.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:w].active = YES;
        [v.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:w].active = YES;
        [v.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:x].active = YES;

        [topConstraints addObject:[v.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:100.0]];
        [views addObject:v];

        x += w + 8;
    }
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:topConstraints];
}

-(void)animViews {
    __block int i = 0;
    __block CGFloat newConstant = ((NSLayoutConstraint *)self->topConstraints[0]).constant == 0.0 ? 100.0 : 0.0;
    ((NSLayoutConstraint *)self->topConstraints[i++]).constant = newConstant;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        ((NSLayoutConstraint *)self->topConstraints[i++]).constant = newConstant;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            ((NSLayoutConstraint *)self->topConstraints[i++]).constant = newConstant;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                ((NSLayoutConstraint *)self->topConstraints[i++]).constant = newConstant;
                [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    ((NSLayoutConstraint *)self->topConstraints[i++]).constant = newConstant;
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        ((NSLayoutConstraint *)self->topConstraints[i++]).constant = newConstant;
                        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            NSLog(@"All Done!");
                        }];
                    }];
                }];
            }];
        }];
    }];
}
@end
```